Typescript Compiler API: JsDocs skipped even when using ts.createPrinter({removeComments: false })
I'm trying to generate function declarations from methods of an interface. Although the function are correctly created their JsDocs is missing, even when I explicitly say to the printer not to remove them.
Here is a simplify version of my interface:
//api-interface.ts
export interface SourceInterface {
  /**
   * 
   * The source of the data.
   * 
   * @param label The label to be used as the source for the data.
   */
  source: <T>(label: T) => void;
}

I'm expecting to generate the following file:
//api.ts

/**
* 
* The source of the data.
* 
* @param label The label to be used as the source for the data.
*/
export declare function source<T>(label: T): void;

Here is my code to generate the api.ts file using the Typescript API (^5.3.3)
//generate-api.ts

import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const interfaceFile = './api-interface.ts';
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  interfaceFile,
  fs.readFileSync(interfaceFile, 'utf8'),
  ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
  true,
  ts.ScriptKind.TS
);

// Function to generate function declarations from interface
function generateFunctionDeclarations(node: ts.Node): ts.FunctionDeclaration[] {
  if (!ts.isInterfaceDeclaration(node)) return [];

  const functionDeclarations = node.members.map(member => {
    if (ts.isPropertySignature(member) && member.type && ts.isFunctionTypeNode(member.type)) {
      const functionName = (member.name as ts.Identifier).text;
      const functionIdentifier = ts.factory.createIdentifier(functionName);
      const typeParameters = member.type.typeParameters;
      const parameters = member.type.parameters;
      const returnType = member.type.type;
      const jsDocTags = ts.getJSDocTags(member);
      const modifiers = [
        ts.factory.createModifier(ts.SyntaxKind.ExportKeyword),
        ts.factory.createModifier(ts.SyntaxKind.DeclareKeyword)
      ];

      const functionDeclaration = ts.factory.createFunctionDeclaration(
        modifiers,
        undefined,
        functionIdentifier,
        typeParameters,
        parameters,
        returnType,
        undefined
      );

      if ('jsDoc' in functionDeclaration) functionDeclaration.jsDoc = jsDocTags;

      return functionDeclaration;
    }
   return undefined;
  }).filter(value => value !== undefined);

  return functionDeclarations;
}

const functionDeclarations = sourceFile.statements.flatMap(generateFunctionDeclarations);
const apiFile = ts.createSourceFile('api.ts', '', ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, false, ts.ScriptKind.TS);
const result = ts.factory.updateSourceFile(apiFile, functionDeclarations);

const printer = ts.createPrinter({removeComments: false });
const resultText = printer.printFile(result);
fs.writeFileSync('api.ts', resultText);


Any idea what I'm missing?
Here is a TS Playground where I just read the interface code from a variable and print the result to console using the global ts object, which is available in the Playground
